# Excel VBA macro: Extract Date from String as dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, string, date, text-extraction

I have an Excel sheet with a formatted cell as text with a timestamp from I need to extract the date in format dd/mm/yyyy and store the result in a cell as date. What I normally do on other calculations is get the result for first line, populate to bottom line, then copy and paste as values, not the formula itself. The file could have 30000 lines.

I have tried with the date function which works fine on the sheet, but not on the VBA code.

Any help are welcome

[The Excel sheet look as the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l9P0.jpg)

Comment: What is your question?  It seems you may want VBA, but you do not show any VBA code, nor do you use the VBA tag.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will automatically recognize most dates.  By only supplying the first 10 characters of the string, i.e. the date, Excel will know what to do with it.

Your formula could be simplified, into a cell with a dd/mm/yyyy format:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))
```

The corresponding VBA function would look like:

```
Format(Left(Range("A1").Value, 10), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```